# SignalR application crashes in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, signalr, signalr.client

I have a signalR application which runs smoothly on Firefox, Chrome and Safari. It even works fine on Microsoft Edge.

But when I run the application on Internet explorer it works fine for some time, and then the IE crashes with the following message:

[image: IE CRASH ERROR]

I once opened it in the debugger and it says:
**Unhandled exception at 0x0724166F (mshtml.dll) in iexplore.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.**

Is there something wrong with my application. What's the way round this error because the client needs this application on Internet Explorer. The version I checked it on is Internet Explorer version 11.0.32

Comment: This reminds me of all the undocumented and unknown State errors that IE has always had.  Unfortunately, the message is mostly worthless, and it's most likely something deep inside of IE that only MSFT knows about.  I personally gave up on IE many years ago as a result of this type of issue. The only option you have is to open a ticket with MSFT to resolve.

Comment: I hate IE mostly for this reason. I don't recommend IE to my customers at all, but once in a blue moon a request comes in and it is non-negotiable. Thanks for the comment though I will check with MSFT

Comment: Here's the weird thing. When I run the application normally, the application crashes executing the SignalR.

When I open the developer tools on IE (on the same PC) it works fine. It's bizarre

Comment: Try disabling the ajax cache. If you're using angular, set its cache off as well. Do you know if it works on first use?

Comment: @Dispersia already did that in jquery `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`

Comment: Are you using template engine ?

Comment: Nope. No template engine